# A more polite/formal way of saying "contact us, we will get back to you"

Tags: formality, business-language

I'm doing some language correction for my mom's company website. While my English is much better than hers, I'm not a native speaker, and I've never really focused on business English in my studies. I'm rewriting a short introduction to the company, and I came across a sentence that basically means "contact us, tell us what you want, we'll make you an offer asap". So far I have

"We will get back to you with our offer in the shortest time possible."

For some reason, the "We will get back to you" part strikes me as not very formal. It feels colloquial. It doesn't seem to fit with the style and and the level of formality required by the context.

I may be wrong about this, it's just a hunch. Again, I'm not a native speaker. So is there a way to say this more politely? Or is this form acceptable?

EDIT:
the answer to the other question suggests I use "contact you". And since the preceding sentence reads "Don't hesitate to contact us", I'd end up with "contact us ... we'll contact you", which is just bad stylistics. 
Another suggested answer is "reach out" but again, this doesn't have the right connotation (of back-and-forth) with regards to the preceding sentence. I realize now I should have included that sentence in the original question. So really what I need is to transform "Contact us, we'll get back to you" to "Contact us, we'll [...]", [...] being the more formal version.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that one (it's my first day at English exchange). However, the answer to that question suggests I use "contact you". And since the preceding sentence reads "Don't hesitate to contact us", I'd end up with "contact us ... we'll contact you", which is just bad stylistics.

Comment: Why would you give diametrically opposed instructions so close together? Is it *contact us*, or *we'll contact you*? I think that's your problem. *Let us know and we'll get back to you as soon as possible* is perfectly acceptable in all but, *maybe* a law firm.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I only see one instruction in there: "Please contact us". The following is more of a statement about what will happen when you do contact us. A promise, if you will
1. Contact us
2. We'll get back to you asap.
It's intended to be two separate sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem disappears if you use a more exact verb:

*We will **present** our offer to you as quickly as practicable.*

*Respond* would also fit well.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like "Follow up"

It gives a better feeling of completeness and doesn't carry the customer service center connotation that "get back to" does.

i.e.

"We will follow up with our offer as soon as we receive your request."

or

"Once we receive your request we will follow up with our offer."